# Feature request for ASANA API

Tags: asana

There are good advantageous features asana web app has like setting periodical repeating tasks, sections for easy visibility, inbox.. but most of them are not exposed in the API. It would be nice to have a feature request page or email to post our requests. We are eager to see more features exposed through APIs.

Comment: feedback@asana.com is an email address might help for the purpose, but do not know if they accept FR for APIs throught this email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I work at Asana) Feature requests are welcome, and they can be directed to the API support email address found at http://developer.asana.com